# Invalid character \u0000 in Spring PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore file

Tags: java, spring

As shown in the code below, we have an `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` with a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` using `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore`.

```
@Bean
public PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore getMetadataStore() {
    final PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore() {
        @Override
        public String putIfAbsent(final String key, final String value) {
            try {
                super.afterPropertiesSet();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return super.putIfAbsent(key, value);
        }
    };
    metadataStore.setBaseDirectory(getRegistryValue("LOCALMETASTOREDIRECTORY"));
    return metadataStore;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "CSVChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "30000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
    final String METHODNAME = "ftpMessageSource()";
    if (LoggingHelper.isEntryExitTraceEnabled(LOGGER)) {
        LOGGER.entering(CLASSNAME, METHODNAME);
    }

    final Comparator<File> fileLastModifiedDateComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final File f1, final File f2) {
            return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified())
                .compareTo(f2.lastModified());
        }
    };

    final FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(ftpInboundFileSynchronizer(), fileLastModifiedDateComparator);
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(getRegistryValue("LOCALDIRECTORY")));

    final FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter fileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter = new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(getMetadataStore(),
            getRegistryValue("REMOTEFILENAMEPATTERN_ANAG_CLI"));
    fileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.setFlushOnUpdate(true);

    source.setLocalFilter(fileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter);

    if (LoggingHelper.isEntryExitTraceEnabled(LOGGER)) {
        LOGGER.exiting(CLASSNAME, METHODNAME);
    }
    return source;
}
```

We have 4 instances of the application running in production and the local directory, meta store directory are all on a location shared by all 4 instances.

The problem we facing now is we are seeing invalid characters written in the metadata-store.properties file and sometimes there is some process writing this character `\u0000` continuously and that causes the file to grow in big size, like 1GB in few minutes. And since the metadata is read in to memory by the framework that is causing `outofmemoryexception` when the file is very big.

Please see below some entries from the metadata-store.properties file below.

```
ANAG_CLI_*.CSV/opt/user-integration/anagcli/input/20200609113855907_ANAG_CLI_20200609113846.CSV.a=1591695480000
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000=
ANAG_CLI_*.CSV/opt/user-integration/anagcli/input/20200610105125916_ANAG_CLI_20200610105118.CSV.a.writing=1591779085951
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000=
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000=
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000=
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000=
ANAG_CLI_*.CSV/opt/user-integration/anagcli/input/20200609133155929_ANAG_CLI_20200609133146.CSV.a=1591702315917
```

Is it safe to use the `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` like this in a shared location between more than one application instances? How to understand what is causing this invalid character issue and how to avoid this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a symptom. Fix the cause instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - yeah, correct. But I do not know what is the cause.